# Choose whether "os.system('cmd...')" opens CMD prompt

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd

I am making a python program launcher with tkinter to run my python programs. I am using `os.system('cmd /c ' + command)`, where `command` is equal to `'python "' + file_location + '"'` to run my python programs. This method doesn't open CMD prompt which works great for my GUI based programs where CMD prompt isn't needed to view the output of the program. But with certain programs I want to be able to show the CMD prompt (to view print results etc). Is there a way to modify the above command to allow me to choose whether CMD prompt will open.

Incase it helps, below is the code for the program launcher:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Menu
import threading
import os


window = Tk()
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.title("Program Launcher")
program_data_location = 'D:\Raphael\Python\Code\Program Launcher\program_data.txt'
window.iconbitmap('D:\Raphael\Python\Code\Program Launcher\Logo\logo.ico')


def update():
    with open(program_data_location, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(program_data_location, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if not line.isspace():
                f.write(line)

    for widgets in window.winfo_children():
        if widgets.winfo_class() != "Menu":
            widgets.destroy()

    f.close()

    file = open(program_data_location, 'r')
    counter = 0

    for i in file:
        info = i.split(', ')
        link = info[2]
        play = Button(window, text = "▶", command=lambda link=link: open_file(link))
        play.grid(column = 0, row = counter, sticky = "w,e", rowspan = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

        title = Label(window, text = info[0], font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
        title.grid(column = 1, row = counter, sticky = "w")

        description = Label(window, text = info[1],
                            font = ("Arial", 9))
        description.grid(column = 1, row = counter + 1, sticky = "w")

        counter += 2
    file.close()


def show_programs(event):
    global selected_program_info

    sele_program = programs.get()
    file = open(program_data_location, 'r')

    for i in file:
        info = i.split(', ')
        name = info[0]
        description = info[1]
        location = info[2]
        if sele_program == name:
            selected_program_info = i
            name_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            description_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            location_entry.delete(0, 'end')

            name_entry.insert(END, name)
            description_entry.insert(END, description)
            location_entry.insert(END, location)

    file.close()

def remove_program():
    with open(program_data_location, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open(program_data_location, "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != selected_program_info:
                if not line.isspace():
                    f.write(line)

    f.close()

    update()
    edit_window.destroy()


def edit():
    global programs
    global name_entry
    global description_entry
    global location_entry
    global edit_window

    edit_window = Toplevel(window)
    edit_window.title("Edit Program")

    combofont = ("Arial", 10)
    programs = Combobox(edit_window, width = 32, font = combofont, state = 'readonly')
    programs.set("Select")
    programs.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady = 3, padx = 3, sticky = "w")
    programs.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.font', combofont)
    programs.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', show_programs)

    select_lbl = Label(edit_window, text = "Select program:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    select_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    name_lbl = Label(edit_window, text = "Name:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    name_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    name_entry = Entry(edit_window, width = 40)
    name_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    description_lbl = Label(edit_window, text = "Description:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    description_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    description_entry = Entry(edit_window, width = 40)
    description_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_lbl = Label(edit_window, text = "File location:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    location_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_entry = Entry(edit_window, width = 40)
    location_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_search = Button(edit_window, text = "Browse", command = select_file)
    location_search.grid(column = 2, row = 3, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    add_btn = Button(edit_window, text = "Save",
                     command = lambda: change_text(name_entry.get(), description_entry.get(), location_entry.get()))
    add_btn.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")
    add_btn.config(width = 33)

    del_btn = Button(edit_window, text = "Delete Program", command = remove_program)
    del_btn.grid(column = 1, row = 5, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")
    del_btn.config(width = 33)

    file = open(program_data_location, 'r')

    for i in file:
        all_info = i.split(', ')
        name = all_info[0]
        programs['values'] = (*programs['values'], name)

    file.close()

def select_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = [('Python File', '*.py')])
    location_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    location_entry.insert(END, file_path)

def update_text(name, desciption, location):
    file = open(program_data_location, 'a')
    if name == '' or desciption == '' or location == '':
        error_lbl = Label(add_window, text = "Please fill out all sections", font = ("Arial", 10))
        error_lbl.config(foreground = "red")
        error_lbl.grid(column = 1, row = 4, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")
    else:
        file.write("\n" + name + ", " + desciption + ", " + location)
        file.close()
        update()
        add_window.destroy()

    file.close()

def change_text(name, desciption, location):
    new_text = (name + ", " + desciption + ", " + location)

    with open(program_data_location, 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()

    filedata = filedata.replace(selected_program_info, new_text)

    with open(program_data_location, 'w') as file:
        file.write(filedata)

    update()
    edit_window.destroy()

def run_command(file_location):
    command = 'python "' + file_location + '"'
    os.system('cmd /c ' + command)

def open_file(file_location):
    threading.Thread(target = run_command, args = [file_location]).start()


def add():
    global location_entry
    global add_window

    add_window = Toplevel(window)
    add_window.title("Add program")

    name_lbl = Label(add_window, text = "Name:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    name_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    name_entry = Entry(add_window, width = 40)
    name_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    description_lbl = Label(add_window, text = "Description:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    description_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    description_entry = Entry(add_window, width = 40)
    description_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_lbl = Label(add_window, text = "File location:", font = ("Arial Bold", 10))
    location_lbl.grid(column = 0, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_entry = Entry(add_window, width = 40)
    location_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    location_search = Button(add_window, text = "Browse", command = select_file)
    location_search.grid(column = 2, row = 2, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")

    add_btn = Button(add_window, text = "Add", command=lambda: update_text(name_entry.get(), description_entry.get(), location_entry.get()))
    add_btn.grid(column = 1, row = 3, padx = 3, pady = 3, sticky = "w")
    add_btn.config(width=33)

menu = Menu(window)
new_item = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

new_item.add_command(label='Add Program', command=add)
new_item.add_command(label='Edit Program', command=edit)

menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)

window.config(menu=menu)

update()

window.mainloop()
```

I also have a text file to store all the program locations which is stored in this format:

```
name, description, file_location
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Use `os.system('start cmd /c ...')` to open a command prompt window.

Comment: [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is deprecated since many years and should not be used anymore in newly coded Python scripts. It results on Windows in starting `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c` with the command line to run appended as additional argument(s). There is used the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with [STARTUPINFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) to run `cmd`.

Comment: There should be used the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) which is on Windows a Python wrapper module for `CreateProcess` and structure `STARTUPINFO`. So every executable can be run directly with `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.Popen` without the roundabout route starting first `cmd.exe` which uses also `CreateProcess` with `STARTUPINFO` to run executables. A Python programmer has with `subprocess.Popen` full control on how an executable is started on Windows like without or with opening a window for a Windows console application.

Comment: @Mofi Do you think you can tell me how I would use subprocess to run a python program from a directory and choose whether the CMD prompt appears?

Comment: The Python documentation referenced by me in the previous comment contains all information required for a Python script programmer. There is explained the usage of `subprocess.STARTUPINFO` with `dwFlags` containing the constant (bitmask value) `subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW` and how set `wShowWindow`. I recommend to read first the two Microsoft documentation pages referenced by me in my first comment which makes it more clear how to make use of `subprocess.STARTUPINFO` and `subprocess.Popen` after reading finally also the subprocess module documentation from top to bottom.

Comment: BTW: It is advisable to run `cmd.exe` with its full path. The full path can be determined by using [WindowsPath = os.environ\['SystemRoot'\]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ) and use `"C:\\Windows"` for `WindowsPath` on `WindowsPath` is very unlikely `null` because of `SystemRoot` environment variable does not exist (really unlikely, but not impossible). The string value of `WindowsPath` should be concatenated next with `"\\System32\\cmd.exe"` to get the fully qualified file name of the Windows Command Processor assigned to a variable for usage with `subprocess.Popen`.